# How to remove an NaN and Inf in a formula

Tags: reporting-services

I am writing a report with a column that calculates year over year comps in sales. The problem I am having is that we do not have any sales history that dates before the beginning of this year. I am using the formula below to calcute the percent change but am getting NaN and Inf errors due to the fact that there is zero in the denominator. Is there a way to write this formula to exclude those, perhaps an iif statement?

=(SUM(Fields!MTDInvoiced.Value)-SUM(Fields!PYMTDInvoiced.Value))/SUM(Fields!PYMTDInvoiced.Value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom function to do this, that's probably the best way especially if you will need this often, but the expression only version below should work.

```
=IIF(
    SUM(Fields!PYMTDInvoiced.Value)=0,
    0, 
   (SUM(Fields!MTDInvoiced.Value) - SUM(Fields!PYMTDInvoiced.Value)) 
    / 
    IIF(SUM(Fields!PYMTDInvoiced.Value)=0,1,SUM(Fields!PYMTDInvoiced.Value))
)
```

I've not tested this but hopefully it's correct.

The first thing we do is test is if the denominator is zero, then return 0 if it is. If it's not then we do the standard expression but we again test that the denominator is not zero. Even though this last check will never return the final output, we still have to test for it as each part of the expression is evaluated in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is via VB code.

Go to report properties -> code

paste the following

```
Public Function fdivide (Byval a As Decimal,Byval b As Decimal, Byval c As Decimal) As Decimal
'  Fix for divide by zero problem in VB
' calculates  a/b  and either returns result or c if b = 0 


if b = 0 then 
    return c 
else 
    return a/b 
end if 

end function
```

now on the text box you want to divide, simply call this function like so :

```
=Code.fdivide(Fields!numerator.value, Fields!denominator.value,0)
```

The code is self explanatory. Can be reused without having to worry about nested IFF statements.

Comment: @Dane Thomas When I said "You could write a custom function to do this" this is what I meant, either answer will work but this is easier if you need to do the same process several times. Harry's answer is the better one.